# I tried to insert json data into room database for displaying dummy contacts in UI using mvvm its showing null object reference in java

Tags: java, android

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer)' on a null object reference

I can't fix the problem

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Share your code snippet